# Removing the 'short' code completion in NetBeans

Tags: java, netbeans, code-completion

In the context of declaring a field or method, I type 's' and NetBeans offers a list of possible completions including `static` which is good.

The first option on the list is `short`. I've never used that in Java programming and almost certainly never will, so I'd like to get rid of it and stop it cluttering up the list. I've tried going into Tools/Options, Code Templates, and deleting the `short` template, but that hasn't made any difference. Is there a way to get rid of `short`?

(There are a few other code completion offerings I'd like to get rid of as well; if it's possible, presumably the technique will be the same as in this case.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Code templates are different concept from Code Completion.**

Code templates allow you to expand a shortcut into a snippet of java code (e.g. `psvm` => `public static void main(String[] args) {...}`).

In NetBeans you can exclude packages, classes or methods from code completion:
Preferences -> Editor -> Code Completion -> Language:Java -> Packages/Classes exclude.

**It's currently not possible to exclude primitive types from Code Completion in NetBeans.**